# Importing a JSON object into MongoDB in java

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am trying to import a json into MongoDB in a java program and I am getting the following exception.
Exception in thread "main" org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is ARRAY

This is my source code.

```
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("test2");

MongoCollection<Document> collection = 
          database.getCollection("collection1");

    int count = 0;
    int batch = 100;

    List<InsertOneModel<Document>> docs = new ArrayList<>();

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\\\CsvFiles\\OneMillion.json"))) {
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(Document.parse(line)));
            count++;
            if(count == batch) {
                collection.bulkWrite(docs, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false));
                docs.clear();
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
        if(count > 0) {
            collection.bulkWrite(docs, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false));
        }
}
```

Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?.

Comment: Can you show a sample data in the csv file ?

Comment: Thanks @Veeram for the response. It is a json file.                                                                                                   
[ {
"Series_reference" : "BLDM.SF010001A1A",
"Period" : "1990.04",
"Data_value" : "89",
"Suppressed" : "n",
"Status" : "F",
"Units" : "Number",
"Magnitude" : "0",
"Subject" : "Building Consents - BLD",
"Group" : "Building consents by region",
"Series_title_1" : "Northland Region",
"Series_title_2" : "All construction",
"Series_title_3" : "New",
"Series_title_4" : "Number",
"Series_title_5" : "Actual"
 }]

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813112/mongo-java-driver-3-6-1-how-to-parse-a-json-array-structured-string-to-basicdb) will help you. As noted in the answer you've to parse the json entry as document by converting array into document.

Comment: @Veeram, Here as you can see in my code, I am reading the file, then parsing each line in that file and adding it to the document. Are you saying that before I parse the line(docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(Document.parse(line)));), I should be converting that json into an document and then parse it as a document.?. Can you please elaborate on this as this is the first time I am working with this MongoDb import process. Thanks.

Comment: yes that is correct. Json that you are trying to parse is an array and so you get the error. Convert into document in the java code as shown in the linked answer.

Comment: @Veeram, I am getting an Exception in thread "main" org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Trying to read past EOF . Getting this exception when it is trying to parse the first line in the json file which is [ { .                                                                                    
 My code is as follows. String line; while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
BasicDBObject basicDBObject = BasicDBObject.parse(String.format("{\"a\": %s}",
            line)); docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(Document.parse(basicDBObject.toString()))); Am I doing something wrong with String.format step.

Comment: Your code posted in the question is almost right. Just replace             `docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(Document.parse(line)));` to 
`Document document = Document.parse(String.format("{\"a\": %s}", line));docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(document.get("a")))`

Comment: Thank you @Veeram.Working on it.  I have a question for you. Our goal is to pick a csv file from a sftp server, convert it into json and then import it into MongoDB. So, I have the java program that is working fine for converting the csv to json and then I am working on this program to import that json to mongodb. Do you think this whole process makes any sense or is there a better way of doing it. I got some sample Json documents from online and when tried importing them to mongo, it worked fine., but when trying to import this converted json from csv, I am having the issues with the format.

Comment: It appears you are converting the csv line into array of json values. You should convert into json document  then your code should work as is.

Comment: Sure, will look into it Veeram. Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: @Veeram, I am getting the following error now.                                     
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.bson.Document error .  It is happening at the following line. docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>((Document)document.get("a")));  Basically. document.get("a") is returning an arraylist and it is not able to cast it to the Document. Any idea where it is going wrong?.

Comment: Iterate over array and add it to insert model. replace `docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(document.get("a")))` with `for(Document doc:document.get("a")) {docs.add(new InsertOneModel<>(doc));}`

Comment: Thank you very much @Veeram. That worked.